# submitting the form using enter button

Tags: visualforce

I have a line which I am cloning. the page can be submitted using save button which i have implemented on my page. Also the page can be submitted using enter button from keyboard. Pressing enter button should perform same action as save button is doing. That functionality is implemented as shown in vf page under javascript as :

```
$('input, select, label').on('keydown keyup',function(evt){

             if(evt.which==13){ // enter button
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();
                $('[id$=save]:visible:first').trigger('click');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

but its not behaving as expected. Please guide.
Also, what should i do to debug this code. Consle.log is not printing anything to me when i checked in debug logs. Please help.

Comment: What if you change it to: $('input, select, label').on('keyup',function(evt){

Comment: it worked...this is awesome...thank u some much Eric. Can u pls explain how it is working now ?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$('input, select, label').on('keydown keyup',function(evt){
```

to

```
$('input, select, label').on('keyup',function(evt){
```

The `keydown keyup` is not a valid use of the on() method. If you need to have multiple events you need to use the info found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608145/jquery-on-method-with-multiple-event-handlers-to-one-selector

Also, there is no need to fire on both keyup or keydown anyway